# How to change HTML URL /folder/file.html

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I have a website, I have my root folder and then a sub folder. The file in the sub-folder is called `dashboard.html`.

Here is what the URL looks like:

```
www.website.com/sub-folder/dashboard
```

I used .htaccess to remove .html

I was wondering if there was a way to remove the /sub-folder part of the URL and still have it go to the dashboard.html file.

The end goal is this:

```
www.website.com/dashboard
```

while still keeping it in the sub-folder

The only issue is, I can't move dashboard.html to the root directory because parts of the website don't work unless it's in the sub-folder.

Just wondering if there was an easy way to do this or if it simply wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard /sub-folder/dashboard.php [NC,L]
```

It works with .php. I think it might also work with .html.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. I even tried making a `dashboard.php` file within my sub-folder that contained the PHP code:

`<?php header( 'Location: /dashboard' ) ;  ?>`

Since I was using Heroku to host the website this is what I had to do to specify the `index.html` file so Heroku would know where to go.

But, unfortunately that didn't work either.